# delete products with a specific attribute

Tags: mysql

I have an attribute which is called manufacturer (attribute code: manufacturer) 
and I want to delete all sku's that are from a specific manufacturer.

However I am not sure how to write the SQL (I want to do this via Mysql) 
I know the basic query to delete a product would be like

```
  SELECT * FROM magento.catalog_product_entity where sku='abc';
```

any suggestions?
thank you!

Comment: Thank you Sander Mangel do I just need to put include('app/Mage.php'); on the top of the file I would have your code in?

Comment: I get a 500 server error when I try to load your code

Comment: When you add comments here I don't get notified.  A 500 error means the error is not shown. Please check your Apache logs what the error is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Magento works with an EAV structure deleting data from the `catalog_product_entity` table is not enough. You'll also need to delete the data from other tables.

Using Magento objects might be easier and ensures a cleaner database.

A script like the following would do the trick

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', [id]);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
   $product->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for delete one or multple products from mysql in magento.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` IN ('SKU1', 'SKU2', ...., 'SKU1000');
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25412/delete-multiple-products-in-magento