# how to bulk delete products from magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, csv

I have multiple products that I need to delete from magento.
Found this thread [Delete multiple products in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25412/delete-multiple-products-in-magento) and tried both scripts, however when I load mysite.com/script.php I get http error 500.

Both php and CSV files are in root directory.
in the script I have changed filenames to match csv file and also corrected the path to mage app accordingly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be running `sql` script from phpmyadmin or as sql as @Marius suggested.

Go to your database (phpmyadmin) and run this script.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` IN ('SKU1', 'SKU2', ...., 'SKU1000');
```

add all your other sku. Please make backup of your database before doing so.

**But** if you wish to do it through magento then follow @Doug McLean solution:

Create a csv file having all your sku, 1 in each row, having `sku` in first row.

Then go to `System > Import/Export > Import` then in import page choose `Import Behavior` to "Delete Entities" and upload the file and proceed.

[image]

Then clear the cache.

Comment: suppose if i want to delete products from the selected store, what is my CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try these following step according your requirement.**

> **Solution 1 :- To delete all products you can use this query:**

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**> Solution 2 :- To delete some select products you can use this:-**

> In order to delete products, you can simply use backend:
>
> Catalog > Manage Products > Select all checboxes and choose Action =
>   Delete and hit submit.
>
> This may work very good for some thousands of products.
>
> **> Go to System -> Index Management, select and Re-index,after clear cache**
>
> Hope It's helpful for any one.